# Contract public variables stay undefined. Why?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-deployment, contract-debugging

I have a contract that looks like this:

```
contract MainContract is usingOraclize {
    ...

    address minter;
    uint public returnRate;

    ...

    function MainContract(uint _returnRate) {
        minter = msg.sender;
        returnRate = returnRate;
        oraclize_setProof(proofType_TLSNotary | proofStorage_IPFS);
    }        

    modifier onlyMinter {
        if (msg.sender != minter) throw;
        _;
    }

     function updateReturnRate(uint newReturnRate) onlyMinter {
        returnRate = newReturnRate;
     }

     ...    

}
```

I have deployed it on the testnet: https://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0x5cad3cbdbf64b65174b36269f5201d3265569f2b

However, when I try and get the value of the 'returnRate' variable, I get that it is undefined even though it should have been set upon contract creation. So I then tried to update it through the updateReturnRate function and it is still undefined. And I can't explain why...

Do I have to specify the function as being public? Even so why didn't the value get set upon contract creation?

I am using the browser solidity compiler for testing.

Comment: Your parameter is _returnRate (underscore prefixed) so you should initialize returnRate via `returnRate=_returnRate;`

Comment: Ah right oops... Forgot the underscore. But how come I can't update it using the update function?

Comment: For the `updateReturnRate` function. it should work, nothing wrong in your code.The only reason it might be is if the transaction is sent by somebody else than `minter` (contract owner). Otherwise, any exception ? Also for the writing method,I advice to return a successful flag `function updateReturnRate(uint newReturnRate) onlyMinter returns(bool successful){
        returnRate = newReturnRate;
  return true;
     }`

Comment: As it turns out looking at the blockchain: https://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0x5cad3cbdbf64b65174b36269f5201d3265569f2b the transaction was not being sent from the same address as the contract creation address. Although I do not know why the browser solidity compiler called a function from an address that is not mine.

Comment: Even with the same address as the creation address, it doesn't update it. Here is the transaction hash: https://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0xc1b6db9530e47d28ec743be5c021cf58a3ab3f068f8e153a8777306dba74824a sent from the same address as the contract creation address: https://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0x5cad3cbdbf64b65174b36269f5201d3265569f2b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick look, your contract is working fine. I think there is definitely something wrong with [**Browser Solidity**](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity)

I'm usually developping with [Truffle](https://github.com/ConsenSys/truffle), so I quickly made a Truffle project of your contract (below)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;
contract MainContract {
    address minter;
    uint public returnRate;

    function MainContract(uint _returnRate) {
        minter = msg.sender;
        returnRate = _returnRate;
    }        
    modifier onlyMinter {
        if (msg.sender != minter) throw;
        _;
    }
     function updateReturnRate(uint newReturnRate) onlyMinter {
        returnRate = newReturnRate;
     } 
}
```

I compiled the contract and deployed it :

And tested it in the console. Here is the result :

```
truffle(default)> var c = MainContract.deployed()
truffle(default)> c.returnRate.call()
{ [String: '20'] s: 1, e: 1, c: [ 20 ] }
truffle(default)> c.updateReturnRate(30)
'0x642d24031f582730000c37dd254173944840e5e771fbb0b74c032bd74f7294ba'
truffle(default)> c.returnRate.call()
{ [String: '30'] s: 1, e: 1, c: [ 30 ] }
```

The contract initializes the rate to 20. And I changed it to 30 calling updateRate function.

Anyway, I'm not expert in Browser Solidity but I recommend tools like Truffle to industrialize your development and be more efficient.

Everything is [there](https://github.com/gjeanmart/stackexchange/tree/master/9990)